# Windows 10 Icon not showing up on Notification Bar

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-10-upgrade

Please help me for some reason the Windows 10 icon isnt showing up. I have a Windows 8.1 It dosn't show up.Also i have all my updates installed. Please Help Me. i cant reserve a copy for Windows 10 and im really worried because like this is only for a limited time so if you know anything to fix *Please Help Me Asap*

Answer (score 3):

From Windows 10 FAQ & Tips,
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-10-faq

**If you don’t see the Get Windows 10  app on your PC, it might be because:**

1. Your device isn’t up-to-date with at least Windows 7 SP1 or Windows 8.1 Update.
2. Windows Update is turned off or is not set to received updates automatically.
3. You’ve blocked or uninstalled the necessary Windows Update functionality.
4. Your device is not running genuine Windows.